# %matplotlib inline ValueError

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

When I use %matplotlib inline in my program, I get a ValueError. What does this error mean, and how can I resolve it?

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 40, in <module>
ct.iloc[:-1,:-1].plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,color=['red','blue'],grid='false')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line  1735, in plot_frame
plot_obj.generate()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 907, in generate
self._adorn_subplots()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line  1012, in _adorn_subplots
ax.grid(self.grid)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2176, in grid
b = _string_to_bool(b)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 54, in _string_to_bool
raise ValueError("string argument must be either 'on' or 'off'")
ValueError: string argument must be either 'on' or 'off'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the final line of your traceback can be very useful. One of the string arguments you are passing should only be `'on'` or `'off'`. Based on this we can then look at the grid option as this is a boolean option.

I tested this like so:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([23,4],[4,6])
plt.grid('false')
```

giving the same error you got.
To fix this you should use either `grid = 'off'` or `grid = False` as options. In my example above I would change that to `plt.grid('off')`